# Java "unmappable character for encoding UTF-8" error

Tags: java, heroku, encoding

I'm trying to push my java maven server to heroku.
when I debug in Eclipse I have no problems, but when I try to push to heroku I get the following error:

code: `throw new MinyanException("�� ���� ���� �����", MinyanException.ERR_UNKNOWN_KEY, "key");`

error: `"unmappable character for encoding UTF-8"`

The reason is that I have **hebrew** characters in my code.
I tried to Google but no solution worked...
Thank in advance!

Comment: what is that character in question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @lcarus this is the line `throw new MinyanException("�� ���� ���� �����", MinyanException.ERR_UNKNOWN_KEY, "key");`

Comment: Can you try replacing the characters with `\ufffd\ufffd\u0020\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0020\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0020\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd` ?